# Natural Pattern

Tags: pattern, visual, situation

Once, while I was traveling on a vehicle in the Caribbean, I watched a pattern form over the course of about 30 minutes. The rendering below is an approximation  of that pattern from memory. The gray color is true, and represents an entire surface that’s visible from the interior of the vehicle. The blue color is more symbolic than true, and  depicts the approximate pattern that formed naturally on the gray surface.

To avoid giving away too much, I left out some details, such as which way is up or forward, where the seats are, and the size of the surface. I also simplified the surface to be square-shaped, when it's actually rectangular.

What is the vehicle, and how did the pattern form?

Update: I didn't anticipate so many different, feasible answers, so I will narrow it down with this additional info. The gray is the solid, opaque interior floor of the vehicle.

[image: blue lines pattern on gray background]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it a

> bus

The pattern is

> a wet trial caused by a bit of water on the ground that moves as the bus accelerates, brakes and turns.

Comment: Close enough! I'm accepting this answer before the puzzle gets closed. The intended answer is rot13(N obng, haqre jnl. Envajngre vf gevpxyvat va sebz gur fvqrf, naq gur jngre vf znxvat frzv-enaqbz cnggreaf ba gur pbirerq qrpx nf gur obng ebpxf naq ebyyf qhevat vgf iblntr.)

Answer (score 4):

> **It's a ship/boat**

Explanation

> When you're on holidays you have the chance to enter a sightseeing ship with underwater 'windows'. You looked out of one of these and saw a snail moving across the window

Answer (score 3):

I think that it is the

> rear window of a boat in fog, or an aircraft in clouds. As the Caribbean is not typically associated with fog, the aircraft is actually more likely. The fog itself is grey and featureless, and the glass will be riddled with very small water droplets, but in some places, the droplets become big enough to form drops which get pushed around the window by turbulent air. It should be the rear window because front windows will typically have wipers, and on side windows, the drops should be pushed backwards.

Because of this, and the mechanism that causes the lines to form and be as wiggly as they are, I'd assume the vehicle was a

> Helicopter.

Answer (score 2):

Is it a

> car and there's a bug/bugs crawling on the outside of a dusty windshield?

Comment: Nope, sorry that's not it.

Comment: @FlanMan It doesn't seem to conflict with any information in the question. So are we meant to keep guessing until you say "yes, that's the one I was thinking of"?

Answer (score 0):

Were you in:

> a Shark-mobile, and, as you approached a shoal of unwitting fish:
>
>  [image: fish swimming away from a shark, in panic]
>
>  not all of them got away, and they left a nasty blood stain on the Shark-screen?

Answer (score 0):

I could be completely wrong about this, but is it

**Vehicle**

> Aircraft

**Pattern**

> The Patterns of roads over Antigua? It could also be multiple roads/landmarks over multiple islands since the aircraft would be moving and I can't make all the roads *fall in line*.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a

> Rocket or an airplane

and the drawing represents

> Blue rivers on dry fields, probably in summer